# How can I change textual dates to numbered ones in Python?

Tags: python, list, date, replace

I have a Python 3.2.2 program and within it is a list that is something like this:

```
['January 26, 1991', 'February 29, 2012', 'December 10, 2094']
```

without using a million "if" statements, how might I take the list and change it or create a new list that looks like this:

```
['01261991', '02292012', '12102094']
```

basically convert the full date format into a mmddyyyy format?

I've looked at a variety of other questions on here and can't seem to find one like this already. If anybody could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: Are you allowed to use standard library modules?

Comment: Also, your outputs are inconsistent.  Do you want commas or not?

Comment: instead of using if statements use a dictionary, `{'january':01,'february':02,'march':03.....}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't wanna use any `modules` you can try this:

```
dates=['January 26, 1991', 'February 29, 2012', 'December 10, 2094']
def converter(x):
   x=x.split()
   dic={'January':'01','February':'02','March':'03','April':'04','May':'05','June':'06',
         'July':'07','August':'08','September':'09','October':'10','November':'11','December':'12'
        }
   month,day,year=dic[x[0]],x[1][:-1],x[2]
   if len(day)==1:
     day='0'+day

   return month+day+year

new_lis=[]

for x in dates:
   new_lis.append(converter(x))

print(new_lis)

['01261991', '02292012', '12102094']
```

Comment: It's not really good form to give a complete finished-code answer to a homework problem. Also, your code will fail on any day of the month that is not double digits (it strips the comma correctly, but then gives an invalid final string).

Comment: Thanks for the help. The ".split()" function is what really helped me out.

Comment: @HughBothwell Yeah! I missed the case when day of the month is a single digit number, solution fixed. For homework thing, I didn't saw the homework tag, that's why wrote the whole solution.

Comment: @Ivan As `hughbothwell` suggested there's a edit in the solution just before the return statement in `converter` function, `if len(day)==1:day='0'+day`

Answer (score 1):

Python has at least two modules for dealing with time.  (The first is `time` and the second is `datetime`).  Specifically look at `strftime` and `strptime` which are methods for creating "time objects" from strings and then creating strings from "time objects".

Also note that in python, lists are typically represented as '[ item1, item2, ... ]' (square brackets, not curly braces -- curly braces are used for dictionaries ...).

And finally, your final desired date string doesn't conform to the same rules as the other 2...

Comment: I think that the homework just calls for manipulating the string when it is given. What I mean is that
 ['January 26, 1991', 'February 29, 2012', 'December 10, 2094']
is hard-coded into the program. I just need to manipulate it into a mmddyyyy format. How might I go about doing that? Sorry for the typos earlier.

Answer (score 1):

For time manipulations you should generally have a look at the [time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) or [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) modules in the standard library.

```
>>> import time
>>> raw_string_list = ['January 26, 1991', 'February 29, 2012', 'December 10, 2094']
>>> struct_time_list = [time.strptime(raw_string, '%B %d, %Y') for raw_string in raw_string_list]
>>> final_list = [time.strftime('%m%d%Y', struct_time) for struct_time in struct_time_list]
>>> final_list
['01261991', '02292012', '12102094']
```

For this case we use 2 functions of the `time` module: [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) to convert the string back into a time.struct_time and [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) to turn it back into a new string.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the built-in datetime module, specifically [strptime and strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).  Utilizing the [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) to apply a conversion function to each element of the list, you could do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime

dateList = ['January 26, 1991', 'February 29, 2012', 'December 10, 2094']

def convertDate(dateString):
    dt = datetime.strptime(dateString,"%B %d, %Y")
    return dt.strftime("%m%d%Y")

print map(convertDate,dateList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do want `strptime` and `strftime`: I think the `p` is for "process" and the `f` is for format.

They both take a format string and an argument to process according to that string. The `str*time` functions have a rich history dating back to C, what python has is pretty directly related to the original functions, except that it's nicer.

I say that it's nicer because, if you look at [`strptime` and `strftime` behavior](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) you'll see that the format strings have their own mini language, and it's just barely non-intuitive enough for you to make serious mistakes that are hard to spot. (I still need to look up whether minutes are capital- or lower-case m, for example.)

Also, if you're on Linux (and maybe OSX?) `man strptime` I find more helpful than the python docs. The same is true for `strftime`.

Answer (score 0):

First, split the string into three chunks:

```
'January 26, 1991'.split()    # results in ['January', '26,', '1991']
```

Second, use a dictionary to turn the month name into a two-digit number:

```
months = {'January':'01', 'February':'02'}
months['January']     # results in '01'
```

Third, strip the comma from the day and make sure it is two digits.

Fourth, reassemble month + day + year to get your final result.

Fifth, wrap that into a function and apply the function to each element in your list.

Answer (score 0):

The following Python code will accomplish your task:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from time import strptime, strftime
input = ['January 26, 1991', 'February 29, 2012', 'December 10, 2094']
date_list = []
output = []

for i in input:
    date_list.append(strptime(i, '%B %d, %Y'))

for dd in date_list:
    output.append(strftime('%m%d%Y', dd))
```